# C# WebService client returns all NULL, SoapUI returns correctly with the same call

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, soapui, webservice-client

I have the following problem:
I want to consume a WebService in order to collect some data with a .NET application (C#). I've added the WSDL using Visual Studio "Wizard" and everything seemed ok.
When, finally, I called the WebService it returns me the correct number of records (14 lists) with all fields "inside", but most of them (and NOT all) are NULL. Only 4 fields have a correct value.
With a SoapUI call everything is ok: all fields have the correct values.

Following what I tried to solve the issue:

- I tried to change the encoding, with no success.
- I tried with Fiddler and it seems that the WebService returns the correct XML with all values. It is interesting that the 4 values I managed to collect with the application are the first 4 of the answer xml.
- I tried with SoapUI to consume the WebService with the SoapUI default request XML and with the request XML generated by my application (taken from Fiddler): the XMLs are slightly different but on SoapUI the WebService answers the same way, correctly, with All fields with the proper value.
- I checked if the WSDL has been correctly imported and the class has been properly generated (for example field type and so on), in particular comparing the fields that work and the ones not working, but I don't see any difference (they are all strings).

Now I finished my idea. Can someone help me somehow?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please read [tour], [ask] and [mcve] to improve your question

Comment: We would need at least a sample of the data/wsdl/code. Nothing to go on now.

Comment: Are you working in the same Environment (VS vs SoapUI)? Can you post some code?

Comment: I solved the problem! It was due to the fields order! Visual Studio automatically set an order to the fields but it was wrong; I commented all the order parameters and now it's working!! I lost 1 day on it...